# Fibonacci Workings

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers, data-structure

The Fibonacci number sequence is given by

$$F_n = F_{n−1} + F_{n−2},\ n \ge 2,\\F_0 = F_1 = 1$$

Suppose we write two consecutive Fibonacci numbers in the form of a $2 \times 1$ matrix $f$, where

$$
f =
  \begin{pmatrix}
    f_n\\
    f_{n + 1}\\
  \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Show that there is a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ such that when $f$ is multiplied by $A$ we get

$$
  A\begin{pmatrix}
    f_n\\
    f_{n + 1}\\
  \end{pmatrix}
  = \begin{pmatrix}
    f_n\\
    f_{n + 1}\\
  \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Hint: What is $F_{n+1}$ in terms of $F_n$ and $F_{n−1}$?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form

Comment: and [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5023/615567)

Comment: As written, A is the identity.